# Local Network Permission Pop up not coming - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, ios-permissions

Even on adding Privacy - Local Network Usage Description & Bonjour services. Still, I don't see a pop-up on my app to allow or don't allow. Even I don't see my add-in Settings > Privacy > Local Network

I am running the app on iPhone 11 and iPhone 12 Pro (Simulator)

Comment: Are you running any code that would trigger the pop up?  Scanning for bonjour services, for example?

Comment: @Paulw11 - No. But still with out that pop up and permission not seen in Settings > Privacy > Local Network
Code is working fine.

Comment: You will only see the pop up if you execute some code that requires the permission. Simply connecting to devices on your local network does not require the permission. You need to use multicast or broadcast traffic.